# ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INPUT'

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

C++ code as below:

```
vector<string> vA1(A1, A1 + k);
vector<string> vA2(A2, A2 + k);
vector<double> vA3(A3, A3 + k);
vector<string> vA4(A4, A4 + k);
vector<string> vA5(A5, A5 + k);

stmt = con->createStatement("BEGIN ABC.INPUT(:1, :2, :3, :4, :5); END;");
oracle::occi::setVector(stmt, 1, vA1, "VARCHAR2_5_TYPE");
oracle::occi::setVector(stmt, 2, vA2, "VARCHAR2_5_TYPE");
oracle::occi::setVector(stmt, 3, vA3, "NUMBER_10_2_TYPE");
oracle::occi::setVector(stmt, 4, vA4, "VARCHAR2_16_TYPE");
oracle::occi::setVector(stmt, 5, vA5, "VARCHAR2_16_TYPE");
stmt->executeUpdate();
con->commit();
con->terminateStatement(stmt);
```

Oracle script as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE "ABC" as 
  TYPE varchar2_5_type is table of varchar2(5) index by PLS_INTEGER; 
  TYPE number_10_2_type is table of number(10,2) index by PLS_INTEGER; 
  TYPE varchar2_16_type is table of varchar2(16) index by PLS_INTEGER; 
  CAL_MSLP PLS_INTEGER := 0;

  PROCEDURE INPUT(A1_ARRAY in varchar2_5_type,A2_ARRAY in varchar2_5_type,A3_ARRAY IN OUT NOCOPY number_10_2_type,A4_ARRAY in varchar2_16_type,A5_ARRAY in varchar2_16_type); 
end ABC;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY "ABC" as

  PROCEDURE INPUT(A1_ARRAY in varchar2_5_type,A2_ARRAY in varchar2_5_type,A3_ARRAY in OUT NOCOPY number_10_2_type,A4_ARRAY in varchar2_16_type,A5_ARRAY in varchar2_16_type) is
     MSL_VALUE NUMBER(10,2);
  BEGIN
     ......
  END INPUT;
END ABC;
/
```

But when I run the program and call the OCCI function to put the data array into Oracle db, error prompt as below:

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INPUT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INPUT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INPUT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INPUT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INPUT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

How can I fix this issue, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably defining types at the schema level instead of the package level could help